# How to Dynamically Change Email Logo Based on User's Device Theme (Light/Dark) in React Email Template?

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on a react-email template and facing a challenge with dynamically changing the logo according to the user's device theme (light or dark mode). I have two versions of the logo: one optimized for light mode (`logoBlancoUrl`) and another for dark mode (`logoNegroUrl`). Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import {
  Body,
  Button,
  Container,
  Head,
  Hr,
  Html,
  Img,
  Preview,
  Section,
  Text,
} from "@react-email/components";
import * as React from "react";

export function BienvenidaEmailTemplate({ nombre, apellido, token }) {
  const enlaceConfirmacion = `${process.env.APP_URL}/confirm-email?token=${token}`;
  const logoBlancoUrl = `/logo-blanco.png`;
  const logoNegroUrl = `/logo-negro.png`;
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <Preview>
        Janochat - Bienvenido/a {nombre} {apellido}
      </Preview>
      <Body style={main}>
        <Container style={container}>
          <Img
            src={logoNegroUrl}
            width="70%"
            alt="Janochat"
            style={logo}
          />
        </Container>
      </Body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Comment: You question is about theme, but you didn't specify how your theme is stored or where you can grab the current theme. 
Second, why not just go with html5 Picture srcset using media query `prefers-color-scheme: dark`? That will make this fully html and css.

Comment: Im storing the theme on Local Storage, In my app im using Next.js with tailiwnd.

Answer (score 0):

Emails should be converted to html before they are sent. See their [integrations](https://github.com/resend/react-email?tab=readme-ov-file#integrations) section.

So basically you can use the css `prefers-color-scheme` with css.
Or if you would like to use javascript, you can use the `window.matchMedia` function.

Also see https://sreetamdas.com/blog/the-perfect-dark-mode for an example with React.